# How to publish my module in magento Marketplace?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, marketplace

I have developed a module for magento 2. In particular is a custom shipping method, I would like anybody could be able to use my shipping method. 
How can I do to put my module downloable. 
I tried on https://packagist.org but is saying to me that "URLs with user@host are not supported, use a read-only public URL", I have my repo in bitbucket but I dont know how to solve that.
I am not getting the relation between Magento MAarketPlace and Packagist. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

For publishing your extension on marketplace it has many phases which your module need to pass else magento will reject you module there are many phases like:

1. Setup Marketplace Account.
2. Adding Your Product to marketplace.

Once you added your product or module you need to answer few questions.

3. Marketplace Extensions Review Process.

In this process magento will go through your product and review it in every aspects.Once they give your green signal you are ready to go with your product.

For more information you can click [here](https://www.fmeextensions.com/blog/how-to-publish-magento-extensions-in-magento-marketplace/)

Comment: hey @Shubsham, thanks for your answer. I will read this page in details. But I see they talk about selling, I just want to put my module free there. Is in the same place where I should put it?

Comment: Yes its the only place if you want to put it on magnto platform officially else there are many sites where you can put it but i suggest you to publish it here because it worth alot and will help others too.